# EC2 instance restarted, rsa key changed

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

This afternoon I noticed that a manually started service is no longer running on my EC2 instance (standard Ubuntu 9.04 image). When I logged in via SSH I got warning that rsa fingerprint of the host has changed. Uptime was 7 hours and from /var/log/messages I could see that the VM had rebooted this morning. Looked at the dates of files in /etc/ssh, they were all last modified this morning too.

I'm not very familiar with EC2 instances so wanted to ask -- is this behavior normal, what could cause it? Some automatic security updates maybe?

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly from testing, default ubuntu image on EC2 generates it's ssh indetity key on every reboot.

Comment: That's screwed up.

Answer (score 3):

I observed one of my EC2 VMs reboot for no apparent reason on June 30, 2010.

The only information I've found so far is:

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=52417&#52417

> Posted: Jan 23, 2007 4:15 AM PST
>
> We're investigating an open issue that
>   is causing intermittent reboots under
>   certain types of workloads. In the
>   interim we're working to try to
>   isolate customers who have
>   historically exhibited these kinds of
>   workloads.
>
> **Reboots should be
>   expected, but no more frequently than
>   you'd expect them with commodity
>   hardware.**

(emphasis mine)